# More chars on comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, meta, character-limit

Could we get more chars for the comments here in meta?

On lengthy discussions the comments 600 char limit is in some occasions too constricting.

[image: Constricting like a boa.]

Given that meta is <del>an after</del>thought for discussions, this could help a little. :)

---

Ok, there seems to be a consensus that you should be able to get your point across in under 600 chars. Most of the time I'd agree, but I've seen more than once some **heated** discussions where comments had to be broken down.

Of course feel free to tag as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) if correct.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh snake!

Comment: Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Mushroom Mushroom Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Mushroom Mushroom Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Mushroom Mushroom Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Badger Mushroom Mushroom

Comment: 140 characters does sound good.

Answer (score 11):

If 600 characters is not enough then you might need to try writing more concisely.

Comment: Yup. You can say *a lot* in 600 characters if you use the language well. And it will improve your technical writing, so it's worth it.

Comment: Yes, it is a comment, not a review.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Sometimes a reply need to be a bit more explained while is not a basic reply. I think that a feature to request more chars on a certain reply would help to. Think on a 3K user... really you think that such user would lost their time to write so much text if didn't was important in some degree? I agree with concensus, but not for 100% restrictive one. Rule it based on points, manual request or whatever levels you can imagine. Example, able to request 3 long replys each month. You supply the need at the cost the community think. Offer and demand. Trade your points ;=) 0 char left

Comment: Would be better to create separaty replies or just one big?

Answer (score 5):

I think that 600 characters is *way* more than enough. Comments are not supposed to become an on-going discussion between users or long diatribe by one user. That type of protracted discussion is avoided, by design.

Comments are supposed to be a bit Twitter-like; a light-weight way to add a few hundred characters as an annotation to the post. Comments provide *just enough* functionality to point out issues or add any sort of mini "meta discussion" you want to have about the answer.

If you have significant content to contribute, add another answer so it can be voted on independently. **That is the basis of how Stack Overflow works.**

Answer (score 1):

You want to get your point across as quickly as possible, so there really shouldn't be many situations where 600+ chars are required. If that much discussion is required, then it shouldn't occur in comments. :D

Comment: SO engine doesn't encourages discussions at all

Comment: @Jader Dias: but they happen anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It's already been increased from about 300 to 600. Comments are supposed to be a way to, well, comment on a post - *not* a discussion forum. The limit needs to be set somewhere, and 600 seems perfectly reasonable.

I agree with [Jon B](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24570/more-chars-on-comments/24572#24572), if you need to type more than 600 characters, you should either write more concisely, or.. create your own answer and quote the parts you wish to reply to, as I am doing here..

Besides, Twitter seems to be doing fine with 140!...

Comment: remember, it started at 300 (not 200). So we doubled it.